# about while (!(cin>>x))

Tags: c++, while-loop

Why do I have to input the number twice when I run the program below?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int x;
    int number;

    cout << "Please enter a integer ." << endl;
    cin >> number;

    while (!(cin>>x)) 
    {
        cout << "Invalid value !" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Your number is " << number << " ." << endl
```

Comment: why do you have x and integer as variables?? what is the purpose of x???!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use

```
cin >> number;
```

And then

```
   while (!(cin>>x))
```

Both of which read a number.

Comment: if cin>>number fails no opportunity for x to be assigned. eg: if the user inputs a letters to integer

Answer (score 1):

you are taking input two times from user.the Ist input is for number variable and the other is for x variable in while loop.The while loop condition means "take input from user and when user enters an integer then stop the loop".so first time loop begins and value is assigned to x condition becomes false and the line after loop executes. And also not use return 0 statement in loop .To terminate a loop c++ uses break statement :)